# Count all co-occurances of a pair of strings in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, counting, subset

I am trying to obtain a co-occurance matrix for pairs of names in a collection of groups of names.

So, I have a collection of letters in small groups, such as

```
{{a,b,f},{a,b,d,f},{a,c,h},{b,h},{a,b,g}}
```

I need to count the co-occurances of a pair of letters, such as {a,b}, in these groups.

So, in this case, {a,b} occur together in the list at part 1, 2 and 5, so a and b occur together 3 times.

I have

```
namelist = {{a, b, f}, {a, b, d, f}, {a, c, h}, {b, h}, {a, b, g}};
allnames = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@namelist];
allpairs = Subsets[allnames, {2}];
countoccurances[x_] := Count[ContainsAll[#, x] & /@ names, True];
countoccurances[{a, b}]
```

which gives an output of

> 3

as expected. This is obviously very slow given the names list might contain 10,000 entries and so about 50 million pairs, each of which needs to be checked to obtain a co-occurance matrix. Is there are faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matching is not very fast. So I am not sure if pattern matching will serf your needs. You will have to try it out.

With the data:

```
namelist = {{a, b, f}, {a, b, d, f}, {a, c, h}, {b, h}, {a, b, g}};
allnames = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@namelist];
allpairs = Subsets[allnames, {2}];
```

The count for every pair is:

```
Count[namelist, {___, Sequence @@ #, ___}] & /@ allpairs

{3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**
I misunderstood the question. The two letters do not have to be adjacent, and order doesn't matter (ex `{b,c,a}` counts as having an `{a,b}` pair):

```
countOccurences[lst_, x_] := Total[SubsetCount[#, x] & /@ lst]
```

---

Partition `nameList` into runs of 2 adjacent elements (within the same element of `nameList`) and Flatten together into a single list:

```
namelist = {{a, b, f}, {a, b, d, f}, {a, c, h}, {b, h}, {a, b, g}}
pairs = Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ namelist, 1];
(*{{a, b}, {b, f}, {a, b}, {b, d}, {d, f}, {a, c}, {c, h}, {b, h}, {a, 
  b}, {b, g}}*)
```

and `Count`:

```
cts = Counts@pairs
<|{a, b} -> 3, {b, f} -> 1, {b, d} -> 1, {d, f} -> 1, {a, c} -> 
  1, {c, h} -> 1, {b, h} -> 1, {b, g} -> 1|>
```

making it a function:

```
ClearAll[countOccurances, pairs, cts]
countOccurances[lst_, letters_] := (
  pairs = Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ lst, 1];
  cts = Counts@pairs;
  If[MemberQ[Keys@cts, letters], letters /. cts, 0]
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! Note, I think I need `pairs = Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ namelist, 1]' as co-occurrence can occur even if pairs are not adjacent in one of the sublists.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for the misunderstanding. Also does order matter? So would `{b,c,a}` count as having an occurence of `{a,b}`?

Comment: Yes, because they co-occur. Also no need for apology!

Answer (score 4):

Not very fast, I suspect:

```
l={{a,b,f},{a,b,d,f},{a,c,h},{b,h},{a,b,g}};

SequenceCount[#,{a,b}]&/@l

Total[%]

(* 
  {1,1,0,0,1}

  3
*)
```

Or, if speed is a major consideration, maybe:

**Scan**

```
Reap[Scan[Sow[SequenceCount[#,{a,b}]]&,l];,_,Total[#2]&][[2,1]]

(* 3 *)
```

**Do**

```
Reap[Do[Sow[SequenceCount[l[[i]], {a, b}]],{i, Length@l}],_, Total[#2]&][[2,1]]

(* 3 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namelist = {{a, b, f}, {a, b, d, f}, {a, c, h}, {b, h}, {a, b, g}};

sub = Counts @ Apply[Join] @ Map[Subsets[#, {2}] &, namelist]
```

<|{a, b} -> 3, {a, f} -> 2, {b, f} -> 2, {a, d} -> 1, {b, d} ->
1, {d, f} -> 1, {a, c} -> 1, {a, h} -> 1, {c, h} -> 1, {b, h} ->
1, {a, g} -> 1, {b, g} -> 1|>

As `Association` `sub` permits easy and very fast queries:

**1. Get one pair**

```
sub[{b, f}]
```

2

```
sub[{x, x}]
```

Missing["KeyAbsent", {x, x}]

**2. Get several pairs**

`KeyTake`

```
KeyTake[{{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}}] @ sub
```

<|{a, b} -> 3, {a, c} -> 1, {a, d} -> 1|>

`Lookup`

```
Lookup[sub, {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}}, Missing[]]
```

{Missing[], 3, 1, 1}

`KeySelect`

```
KeySelect[MatchQ[{a, _}]] @ sub
```

<|{a, b} -> 3, {a, f} -> 2, {a, d} -> 1, {a, c} -> 1, {a, h} ->  1, {a, g} -> 1|>

**3. Timings**

```
test = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], {10^5, 4}];

(sub = Counts @ Apply[Join] @ Map[Subsets[#, {2}] &, test]); // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.302131

```
sub // Short
```

[image]

```
sub[{"k", "u"}] // Timing
```

{0.000018, 891}

Answer (score 3):

```
occuranceCount[lists_] := 
 Count[lists, {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ #, ___]}, All] &
```

***Examples:***

```
occuranceCount[namelist] @ {a, b}
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
occuranceCount[namelist] @ {b, a}
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
occuranceCount[namelist] @ {f , b}
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

```
occuranceCount[namelist] @ {a}
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

For occurance counts of 2-subsets we can define an association using `occuranceCount` and all pairs occuring in input lists:

```
pairOccuranceCounts[lists_] := 
 Module[{pl = Union @ Apply[Join] @ Map[Subsets[#, {2}] &] @ lists}, 
  AssociationThread[pl, Map[occuranceCount[lists]] @ pl]]

pairOccuranceCounts[namelist]
```

> ```
> <|{a, b} -> 3, {a, c} -> 1, {a, d} -> 1, {a, f} -> 2,   
>   {a, g} -> 1, {a, h} -> 1, {b, d} -> 1, {b, f} -> 2,   
>   {b, g} -> 1, {b, h} -> 1, {c, h} -> 1, {d, f} -> 1|>
> ```

```
Replace[_Missing -> 0] @* pairOccuranceCounts[namelist] /@
 {{a, h}, {a, g}, {a, f}, {c, h}}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 1, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Most` and `Rest`:

```
AdjacentPairs[list_] /; VectorQ[list] := Transpose[{Most[list], Rest[list]}]
AdjacentPairs[list_] /; ListQ[list] := AdjacentPairs /@ list;
CountOccurances[list_, key_] := Extract[Counts[Flatten[AdjacentPairs[list], 1]], Key[key]];

lst = {{a, b, f}, {a, b, d, f}, {a, c, h}, {b, h}, {a, b, g}};
CountOccurances[lst, {a, b}]
(*3*)
```